# How to return a sqrt result in a PHP public function

Tags: php, switch-statement, sqrt

I have a switch case based calculator and I want to return the square root result of a number between 0 and 9. Every other function are working, just the sqrt one that I don't know how to output.

```
<?php
class Calculatrice{
public function calcul($entry = "2+3")
{
   return $this->calculate($entry);
}

private function calculate($data){
    $data_array = str_split($data);
    return $this->operation($data_array);
}
public function operation($array){
    switch ($array[1]) {
        case "+":
            return $this->addition($array[0], $array[2]);
            break;
        case "-":
            return $this->soustraction($array[0], $array[2]);
            break;
        case "*":
            return $this->multiplication($array[0], $array[2]);
            break;
        case "/":
            return $this->division($array[0], $array[2]);
            break;
        case "%":
            return $this->modulo($array[0], $array[2]);
            break;
        case "√":
            return $this->racine($array[0]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public function addition($left, $right){
   return (int)$left + (int)$right;
}
public function soustraction($left, $right){
    return (int)$left - (int)$right;
 }
 public function multiplication($left, $right){
    return (int)$left * (int)$right;
 }
 public function division($left, $right){
    return (float)$left / (float)$right;
 }
 public function modulo($left, $right){
    return (int)$left % (int)$right;
 }
 public function racine($left, $right){
    return (int)sqrt($left);
 }
 }
 ?>
```

I think it's only about displaying the return statement.

Comment: `racine()` is declared to take 2 parameters, you're calling it with only 1 argument.

Comment: How are you writing square root as a string? `calculate()` and `operation()` expect the operator to be the second character, so it should be `5√`.

Comment: It won't work if you write the normal mathematical form `√5`

Comment: not working either

Comment: `str_split()` doesn't work with multibyte characters like `√`. See the linked question for how to split the string properly.

Comment: `√` is a multibyte string, so instead of `str_split()` you must use `mb_str_split()`. Also `racine()` receives one parameter and the `$right` should be omitted.